# What's the difference between "to subscribe to something" and "to agree with something"?

Tags: word-difference

> To subscribe to something is to agree or to concur with it.

This is the definition of "subscribe" in my dictionary.

Then, do those sentences below also have exactly the same meaning?

> 1. She ***subscribed to*** the view that musical education should be kept in schools.
> 2. She ***agreed with*** the view that musical education should be kept in schools.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which dictionary you used, but it's a little odd that it would use the word being defined in its definition in the way that it did.

In Merriam-Webster, the sense of *subscribe* that you are referring to is [defined](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subscribe) as:

> **3** : to assent to : SUPPORT

---

This has mostly the same meaning but there is a difference.

*Agreed with* mostly refers to a single instance of something.

With *subscribed to* there is an implication of *ongoing* agreement, if not actual support. This follows the other sense of *subscribe* where you pay for (or sign up for) something, such as a magazine, and receive regular updates.

So, while you might *agree with* a vote (a single event), you wouldn't say that you *subscribe to* the vote.

---

In your specific example, what's being subscribed to or agreed with is a view, which is something a bit more generalized than a single event. (Somebody can still have the same view months from now.) That's why both words can be used—even if the emphasis is a bit different with each.

So, the following sentence would be understood and not simply taken as repetitious or redundant:

> Not only do I agree with that view, but I actively subscribe to it.

Answer (score 2):

The typical use of *subscribe* is for something like a magazine, newsletter, or other periodicals - publications/websites/forums/posts issued on a regular basis providing talk and updates about the "latest and greatest" of a subject.

So *subscribe* can be figuratively used to mean *accept and follow the latest/greatest of X* if X is something like a "new" point of view, method, philosophy, or simliar.  This does imply you agree with X.

> Then, do those sentences below also have exactly the same meaning?

*Subscribed to X* means more along the lines you are integrating X into your life or work - you change your life, work, routine, or habits due to X especially as you learn more about X.

*Agreed with X* means you agree with X but not necessarily changing your life, routine, or habits due to X.